# Automatically export Google Analytics Atibution (beta)

Tags: web-scraping, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm searching for a way to access the [GA Attribution (beta) project data automatically](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9397590?hl=en).
Especially I need this table (screenshot 1)[image: Download button for Model comparison table].
I want to extract it automatically every day, but I cant seem to find any API for that.

Is there a way to get this data automatically?

I thought about using a webscraper, but I'm not sure if that's allowd/possible on GA.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As off 22.02.2022:

> Thanks for contacting Google Analytics 360 support team. I hope you
> are doing good!
>
> I have reviewed your chat and understand that you are looking for
> option of downloading Model comparison table using API.
>
> I would like to inform that we have already received several request
> from clients on this and our engineers are in the process of reviewing
> the request (feature request). I would like to inform you that I have
> added your details to the list of interested clients and I am looking
> forward to it.
>
> Please note that feature request implementation completely depends on
> our engineers so it is really difficult to provide an estimated
> timeline but I am positively looking forward for the same. If you
> still have anymore questions on the same you may reach out to your
> partner manager and discuss further.
>
> I hope this email helps, in case you have any further questions please
> feel free to reply and I will be glad to assist further.